# Ошибка доступа к файлу: Permission denied

Tags: php

```
if (!file_put_contents("tes.txt", "123123"))
      die("error");
```

1. Если файла нет: `Permission denied`
2. Если файл есть и права стандартные (644): `Permission denied`
3. Если файл есть и права 777: В файл пишется строка
4. Если файл есть в любом случае функция `unlink` дает: `Permission denied`

Файл с кодом имеет права 777. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: быстрый гуглеж подсказал, что нужны права на папку, т.к. удаление и создание файла приравнивается к изменению директории

http://superuser.com/a/373119

что касается пункта 2 - очевидно, запрашивающий пользователь (сервер или php-fpm) не владеет файлом и имеет статус 'group' или 'other'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу предположить, что запуск приложений происходит не от имени юзера, а от имени того же apache, но "владелец" файлов, залитых на сервер, уже пользователь. Я не большой спец в этих вопросах, но погуглите в таком направлении: "[запуск приложений от имени пользователя](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D1%82+%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)"

Answer (score 1):

Да, скорее всего апач(или что у вас работает веб сервером) запускается под пользователем у которого нет прав на файл.
Можно пробовать апач запускать под другим пользователем, или дать пользователю апача права на файл.